# SyntaxError: Illegal character in Kendo UI Template

Tags: syntax-error

I have a `kendo` grid in a page. I need to add Itemtemplate for custom filtering. I want to add it inline, not with a function.

I have started to write the code:

```
...   .Title(LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Status")).Visible(true).Width(110)
      .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true)
      .ItemTemplate(
            "#if (StatusId = 1) { #" + Enums.PublicationStatus.New.ToString() +
            " # } #"       ).CheckAll(false).BindTo(new[] {......}
```

But I keep get the error: `SyntaxError: illegal character`
I have checked here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview
 and it says that the code should be placed between the the `# (hash) sign`.
If I don't add any code only an empty string, I don't get errors.
What am I missing here?